# jQuery Navigation - Keeping the accordion open and show the active page

Tags: jquery, navigation

I have seen a similar related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602963/jquery-accordion-menu-keep-accordion-menu-open-to-the-page-i-am-on) but my situation is a little different so I am posting a new question.

I am working on a site that was built by someone else. The navigation is an accordion style that works nicely but I need to be able to have the navigation remain open with the current active page highlighted. I am relatively new to jQuery and could you some help with:

1. How do I keep the navigation open, and
2. Highlight the active link - I know how to do this part in CSS, but I am not sure how to do that dynamically using jQuery.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this article might help you out  http://www.packtpub.com/article/jquery-ui-accordion-widget-part2

Scroll down to the section "Fun with Accordion".  He talks about using the navigation property and having the menu open and set for the page you are currently on.

Comment: Hey TB, thanks for the link. It will take some adapting, but it is definitely going in the right direction. Thanks for your time.