# Keep Jquery accordion menu open on current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-accordion

I am sure that i will get help in my particular case. No doubt there are many solutions to achieve this but in my case I am unable to achieve it.
Following is my code to generate html dynamically using java script.

**Edit 1: I just want to keep open the current pan of accordion as per `href` attribute of anchor tag which is in fact current page URL. This is it.**

JS code to generate html:

```js
<script>
  $.ajax({
    url: "/categories",
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
      var content = "";

      content += '<div id="category-navigation">';
      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        content += '<div class="head">';
        content += '<label class="categoryLables">' + data[i].title;
        content += '</label>';

        content += '<div>';
        content += '<div class="boardsMargin">';
        content += '<ul>';

        for (j = 0; j < data[i].assigned_boards.length; j++) {

          content += '<li>';
          content += "<a href='/#categories/" + data[i].id + "/boards/" + data[i].assigned_boards[j].id + "'>";
          content += data[i].assigned_boards[j].name;
          content += '</a>';
          content += '</li>';
        }

        content += '</ul>';
        content += '</div>';
        content += '</div>';
        content += '</div>';
      }
      content += '</div>';

      $("#myNavigation").html("");
      $("#myNavigation").html(content);

      $('.head').accordion({
        heightStyle: "content",
        active: true,
        collapsible: true
      });


    }

  });

 </script>
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="myNavigation">
</div>
```

**Edit 2:** For more clear view, this is picture of my accordion.

[image: accordion]

As a side note: I am working in ruby 2.2.1 and rails 4.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` like so:

```
$(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion();
    if (localStorage.getItem('active') != null) {
        $($('h3').get(parseInt(localStorage.getItem('active')))).trigger("click");
    }
});

$('h3').click(function () {
    localStorage.setItem('active', $(this).index("h3"));
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kuvc7t9m/) :)

Note: You may also want to read about `sessionStorage`

Comment: your idea is good but i have edited my question some hours ago that my requirement is to open the particular accordion pan when current URL of page matches the anchor href attribute which is present in list element, I hope you get it .... ! Actually my question is little similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602963/jquery-accordion-menu-keep-accordion-menu-open-to-the-page-i-am-on

Comment: @EM923 It can be done but, can you provide an html structure for the accordion with the _href_ tags included?

Comment: Can you please have a look at my new question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31971860/open-particular-jquery-accordion-pan-based-on-current-page-url . It is more explanatory. If you need more info ,  i will provide it .

Comment: It helps me in making selected accordion pan open after refreshing the page ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `active` option in accordion to the index of panels you want to keep open i.e 0,1,2 etc and set `collapsible` to `false`

As per the docs:

> **Integer:** The zero-based index of the panel that is active (open). A negative value selects panels going backward from the last panel.

Reference: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active

JS:

```
$('.head').accordion({
    heightStyle: "content",
    active: 1, //Change this
    collapsible: false
});
```

Comment: I have just edited it to **active: 1** . But still accordion is collapsed on page refresh! :(

Comment: @EM923 set collapsible to false. Try it

Comment: @K K its not working as well, I have just updated my question.

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle for demo?

Comment: Actually my question is little similar to this question stackoverflow.com/questions/1602963/