# Open particular Jquery accordion pan based on current page URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a `Jquery accordion`, accordion has pan's, list elements and anchor tags in list elements, `href` attributes of anchor tags have current page URL's. **I just want that when a page is visited a particular panel (which contains that anchor tag) automatically opens and its list element should become active.** I have code which make accordion and snippet in end which make list element active. But list element is not active and panel is not opened. I think I am missing something badly. 
Here is code:

```js
<script>
  $.ajax({
    url: "/categories",
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
      var content = "";

      content += '<div id="category-navigation">';
      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        content += '<div class="head">';
        content += '<label class="categoryLables">' + data[i].title;
        content += '</label>';

        content += '<div>';
        content += '<div class="boardsMargin">';
        content += '<ul>';

        for (j = 0; j < data[i].assigned_boards.length; j++) {

          content += '<li>';
          content += "<a href='/#categories/" + data[i].id + "/boards/" + data[i].assigned_boards[j].id + "'>";
          content += data[i].assigned_boards[j].name;
          content += '</a>';
          content += '</li>';
        }

        content += '</ul>';
        content += '</div>';
        content += '</div>';
        content += '</div>';
      }
      content += '</div>';

      $("#myNavigation").html("");
      $("#myNavigation").html(content);

      $('.head').accordion({
        heightStyle: "content",
        active: true,
        collapsible: true
      });

      $('.head li').each(function() {
        li = $(this);
        a = $('a', li);

        myUrl = "";

        myUrl += (location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname +
          (location.port && ":" + location.port));
        myUrl += (a.attr('href'));


        if (myUrl == window.location.href) {
          console.log(myUrl);
          console.log(window.location.href);
          li.addClass('active');

        }
      });

    }

  });

</script>
```

[Brief Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/NabeelNazir/vcrxnedt/16/)

My question is quite similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602963/jquery-accordion-menu-keep-accordion-menu-open-to-the-page-i-am-on). And I am following its 1st answer.

For more clear view, this is picture of my accordion.
[image: accordion]

As a side note: I am working in ruby 2.2.1 and rails 4.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should do the trick:

```
$(document).find("a[href*='" + '/' + window.location.pathname + "']").parents(".head").find("h3").trigger("click");
```

[Example of where to place your code](https://jsfiddle.net/gqgu5q5o/)

Comment: thanks for help, i have come to a small issue that my `href` attribute contain **/#categories/2/boards/3** and  `window.location.href ` returns `"http://localhost:3000/#categories/2/boards/3"` . That is why your above line code returns empty string on browser's console. Can you suggest me how can i make this comparison. Thanks

Comment: Use `window.location.pathname` instead of `window.location.href`, it will give you the relative path. I edited the code in the answer. Please test again and let me know if it works now

Comment: this line of code helps me out ! :)  `$(document).find("a[href='" + '/' + window.location.hash + "']").parents(".head").find("h4").trigger("click");` I just want one more favor of making list element active/ highlighted ! Thanks a lot again !

Comment: @EM923 [here is the updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gqgu5q5o/6/). I added two css classes and toggled them every time the element is clicked using JQuery :)